# phase diagram of a 2x2 system of O.D.E.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\dot x&=&a\,x+b\,y,\\
\dot y&=&c\,x+d\,y
\end{eqnarray}$$
For repeated eigenvalue case, if b−c is positive, then motion is clockwise; if negative, anticlockwise.

For complex eigenvalues case, the motion is clockwise if b−c is positive and anticlockwise if it is negative.

Why can we justify the motion by consider b-c here?

Comment: Here is what I have seen form the web
http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/metric/metric_public/differential_equations/second_order/qualitative_methods_1.html @Moo

Comment: The assertion only makes sense when the eigenvalues are complex conjugate, and then it holds true. To see why, first note that the eigenvalues are complex conjugate only when $bc<0$ hence, when this holds, $b-c>0$ actually means $b>0$ and $c>0$, while $b-c<0$ actually means $b<0$ and $c<0$. Then, if $b>0$, the vector field at points $x=0$, $y>0$, is pointing to the East, which can only happen if the motion is clockwise. Likewise, if $b<0$, the vector field at points $x=0$, $y>0$, is pointing to the West, which can only happen if the motion is anticlockwise. This proves the claim.